Remove labels on contour lines and reduce legend in wake visualization on FLORIS
This is my code to generate the wakes of a 6 turbine farm on FLORIS (image attached). I want to keep the contour lines but remove the velcoity labels on them. I also want to add a legend to the max inflow speed I set. As you can see the legend goes all the way till 9m/s instead of 8m/s and the contour labels can still be seen.
This is for a student project I am doing for my undergraduate studies so any help is most appreciated. Thank you!
`
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import floris.tools.visualization as wakeviz
from floris.tools import FlorisInterface

fi = FlorisInterface("inputs/ccNH6.yaml")

fi.reinitialize(wind_speeds=[8.0])

fi.calculate_wake()

horizontal_plane = fi.calculate_horizontal_plane(height=67.0)
wakeviz.visualize_cut_plane(
    horizontal_plane,
    ax=axarr[0],
    clevels=np.linspace(0, 10, 100),
    color_bar=True,
    contour_labels=False


wakeviz.show_plots()

`
This is what is generated:
enter image description here
This is the link to the visualization directory that contains all the functions used:
[https://github.com/NREL/floris/blob/main/floris/flow_visualization.py]

Please post this question in GitHub Discussions (https://github.com/nrel/floris/discussions) and the NREL team will help.
